# Add columns to a field in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

How can I add 6 more single space separated columns to a file.

The input file that looks like this:

```
-11.160574
...
-11.549076
-12.020907
...
-12.126601
...
-11.93235
...
-8.297653
```

Where `...` represents 50 more lines of numbers.

The output I want is this:

```
-11.160574 1  1  1 1 1 14
...
-11.549076 51 51 1 1 1 14
-12.020907 1  1  2 2 1 14
...
-12.126601 51 51 2 2 1 14
...
-11.93235 1  1  51 51 1 14
...
-8.297653  51 51 51 51 1 14
```

The 2nd and 3rd columns are loops for 1 to 51.

The 4th and 5th columns are also loops for 1 to 51, but at the upper level from above.

The last two ones constants columns of 1 and 14.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 49 more lines?

Comment: Because is for Petrel processing

Comment: I would recommend awk...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, an awk script:

```
{
    mod = 51
    a = (NR - 1) % mod + 1
    b = int((NR - 1) / mod) + 1
    c = 1
    d = 14
    print $0,a,a,b,b,c,d
}
```

Run it with something like `awk -f the-script.awk in-file.txt`.  Or make it executable and add `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` at the top, and you can run it directly without typing `awk -f`.

Comment: great ! thank-you very much, it workd pretty good, there's a '^M' character just after the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to read the file line-by-line and maintain counters to keep track of the field numbers as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
field1=1
field2=1
while read line
do
    echo "$line $field1 $field1 $field2 $field2 1 14"
    (( field1++ ))
    if (( $field1 == 52 )); then
        field1=1
        (( field2++ ))
    fi
done < file
```

Comment: it works great also ! as the awk script I have to get rid of the '^M' character touching the first column